# Update default Javascript variable with ReactJS Hook

Tags: javascript, reactjs, axios

I would like to have following, but working code in my http-axios file:

```
import axios from "axios";
import {useAuthContext} from './services/useAuthContext'

const {user} = useAuthContext();
export default axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:4000/api/",
    headers: { 
        "Content-type":"application/json",
        "Authorization": `Bearer ${user.token}`
    }
});
```

I can not understand how to make my code working because of the continuous dependencies i have.

I call this axios.create export later in an ./services/imgs.js file:

```
import http from "../http-axios";

class VMsDataService {
    getLatest(page=0){
        return http.get(`vms/latest`);
    }
}
```

which i use in App.js file:

```
import VMsDataService from "./services/vms";

VMsDataService.getLatest()
        .then(response => {
            //
        }).catch(e => {
            //
});
```

So my question is. How can i restructure my code to be able to retrieve dynamic data within my axios config and also have this class based functionality i'm having right now. Main point of this is to have dynamic Authorization header taken from useAuthContext component

I tried to turn everything into components but it wasn't successful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A way to create a reusable component, is to create a custom hook.

For example a custom hook that will return user object and set Authorization :

```
import axios from "axios";
import {useAuthContext} from './services/useAuthContext'

const useAxios = () => {
  const {user} = useAuthContext();
  return axios.create({
    baseURL: "http://localhost:4000/api/",
    headers: {
      "Content-type": "application/json",
      "Authorization": `Bearer ${user.token}`,
    },
  });
};

export default useAxios;
```

Then you can use this custom hook in `VMsDataService`.

I am not used to class component, so I wrote it in functional component. I think it is a lot easier :

```
import React from "react";
import useAxios from "../hooks/useAxios";

const VMsDataService = () => {
  const http = useAxios();

  const getLatest = (page = 0) => {
    return http.get(`vms/latest`);
  };

  return {getLatest};
};

export default VMsDataService;
```

Hope I understand clearly what you were asking for !

Comment: Hello, Johan. Thank you very much for your help and it is wroking and that's what i wanted! I actually was trying to do the same, but for now i dont have a clue, why it wasn't working then, lol. Can you tell if "Import React from "react";' matters there?

Comment: Actually no it doesn’t matter. Since react 18 or 17, we don’t need to import it unless we call it somewhere :). Glad that helped !